# How do I use the previous month metric in a formula?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a simple custom metric dividing (`transactions`)/(`Goal Completions`) and getting a percentage. Instead of using the default time frame, I'd like to get the previous months total goal completions instead.

Here's the formula, which gets my the current month transaction divided by current month Goal Completions.

In the image goal completions is called "Free Trials".

I created a custom metric using a Formula in Google Data Studio here:

[image: I created a custom metric using a Formula in Google Data Studio here]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? If you could replicate the issue on a fresh Google Data Studio Report using sample data that would also be proof that it is a reproducible issue! if you could then share that Google Data Studio Report publicly and add a link in the question, it would allow fellow users to test out the issue. Without a Reproducible Example it would be **difficult to pinpoint where the issue lies, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart Configuration, Temporary Outage...**

Answer (score -1):

At first you could insert a new field, which would be a result of comparing the Month and Year of your date field, with the month and year of today's [`TODAY()`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9695546) date. If the comparison is true, it means that it is the current month, so the return will be 0. If the comparison is not true, it means that it is not the current month, so the return will be 1.

`New_Field`:

```
IF (MONTH(data)=MONTH(TODAY()) AND YEAR(data)=YEAR(TODAY()), 0, 1)
```

Afterwards, just insert this new calculated field in your visualization element and use it as a filter:

```
Include New_Field = 1
```